# How to perform the batch updates on table View in ios 10 and below in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios10

I have been using the core data for chat application and updating the chat table in delegate methods of NSfetchResultController controllerDidChangeContent

```
NSMutableArray<NSOperation *> *blockOpetations;
    blockOpetations = [NSMutableArray new];

-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.chatTable beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:{
            [blockOpetations addObject:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
                [self.chatTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
            }]];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) 
    {
        [self.chatTable performBatchUpdates:^
        {
            for(NSOperation *operation in blockOpetations) 
            {
                [operation start];
            }
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) 
          {
            NSInteger lastItem = [self.fetchedResultsController sections] 
                                  [0].numberOfObjects - 1;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastItem 
                                      inSection:0];
            [self.chatTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom 
                      animated:YES];
              }];
    } else {

    }
    [self.chatTable endUpdates];
}
```

I am performing the batch updates on table view for iOS 11 and higher.
I want to perform the batch updates on table in iOS 10 and lower version , since batchupdate is not available below iOS 10.

I want to to know how to perform such thing in lower version.

I have taken the "blockOperation" an array of NSOperation , because if multiple message comes at the same time so table view updates the newly inserted rows serially without crash.

If I may have not taken the BlockOperation then some time the error comes

```
:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (20) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

The code written under method named "ControllerDidChangeContent", want to implement same task in iOS 10 and lower

Answer (score 3):

Before iOS 11, this is done with

```
self.chatTable.beginUpdates()
// do stuff here
self.chatTable.endUpdates()
```

Comment: @JeremLachkar That is what performBatchUpdates gives you.

Comment: I mean, if I need to scroll to bottom after the row are completely inserted, a DispatchQueue.main.async is stable enough ?